# Trouble using the data obtained by javascript browser detect size

Tags: javascript, dom

Being new to javascript I seem to be missing something. I have used this code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    // Get Browser Viewport Width
    var adjust = "<?php echo $adjust; ?>";
    // Get Browser Viewport Height
    var height = window.innerHeight ||
    document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
    document.body.clientHeight;
    // Get Browser Viewport Height
    var height = window.getSize().y;

    window.alert( 'height = ' + (height - adjust) + 'px' );
</script>
```

which works perfectly and gives me an alert to show that the calculation is working fine. However I cannot seem to transfer the height variable correctly to make the div do what I ask.

The following code I have used in the body.

```
<div id="bodyheight">

                </div>
                <script language="JavaScript">
                document.getElementById("bodyheight").style.height = height;</script>
```

Can anyone point in the right direction and fill in the gap in my knowledge.

Comment: First step: Use the script console, to find if it has errors reported. Secondly, defer DOM-manipulation operations till the DOM is available.

Comment: meaning `window.onload=function() { ...all your code including the line in the body...}`

Comment: Thanks for the help... no error messages are being displayed in the javascript console in google chrome..... any other ideas

Comment: actually, just checked again and an error has appeared... Uncaught Type error: Cannot read properly 'style' null... any ideas?

Comment: scrap that, the error was due to code issue caused by playing... now there are no errors and it still doesn't work

Comment: @mplungjan i tried the window.onload function, doesn't solve the problem and no errors in console.... any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here - I do not know from where you get getSize -you had two var height, which is not correct syntax

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vuHML/)

```
window.onload=function() {
// Get Browser Viewport Width
    var adjust = "200";
    // Get Browser Viewport Height
    var height = window.innerHeight ||
    document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
    document.body.clientHeight;
    // Get Browser Viewport Height
    height = (window.getSize)? window.getSize().y:height;
    var newHeight = (height - adjust) + 'px' 
    window.alert(height+' adjusted to '+newHeight);
    document.getElementById("bodyheight").style.height = newHeight;
}
```

Comment: many thanks.. perfect solution.... unfortunately my javascript is very limited ....